# How to create PPPoE connection on my ISP's provided router?

Tags: router, internet, ethernet, pppoe

I have two routers of an ISP. I am using one of them with another ISP after creating a PPPoE connection using eth interface. Second router has no option for creating eth interface so when I tried to create a PPPoE connection and connect to internet, I failed. I am not a technical person and just followed some tutorials to create PPPoE connection in my router. I just know my ISP given username and password. Can you guide me how can I create PPPoE connection using eth interface? Router model is ZTE VDSL CPE ZXHN 168N.

Comment: You should have an ISP supplied or ISP recommended router.   If besides that you want a better router then you could, but if you are not technical then  really I don't know what you are doing. Why don't you just do what your ISP says.

Comment: my current isp didnt give my any router so I used my previous isp router. My previous ISP gave me 2 routers and I was able to create connection on 1 of the router but unable to create on another one (ZTE) router.

Comment: you are only using one router at once though, right?  don't try with two routers simultaneously it's unnecessarily complex!

Comment: Yeah I am only using one, just want to create pppoe settings on another one which has ISP's firmware, not simple one. I searched on youtube and found out that ISP removed the eth interface so that I cannot create pppoe via eth.

Comment: This is what you do. You contact the ISP and get the PPPoE connection details. Then you contact the router manufacturer and ask them how to put them in.  Your router manufacturer should have a phone number or at least an email address

Answer (score 2):

Most routers have a setup area for PPPoE in the WAN section of the router.

Log into the router using the IP Address (often 192.168.1.1) and admin password. This is in the Quick Setup they gave you with the Router.

Then in the Manual (download from ZTE support site) on page 27 is the PPPoE setup with User Name and Password.

Manual is at:  https://www.manualslib.com/products/Zte-Zxhn-H168n-3595606.html

Here is a screen shot from the manual for your router.

[image]

Comment: My router has company installed firmware and settings are not the same screen shot attached. For my another router, I created eth interface and then I was able to create pppoe connection. For this one (zte) this has no setting for creating eth0 settings.

Comment: Call the support organization and ask for the PPPoE setup. I have looked at a lot of routers and they all have some variation of PPP settings shown in the screen shot.   You may need to have them update the firmware.

Comment: Can you give me the link for firmware update for this router? I tried to search on ZTE's website but unable to find any.

Comment: Also I have another issue, I have to run ipconfig release and renew command every few minutes e.g every 15-20 minutes. Can you give me a permenant solution for this issue?

Comment: I posted a link to the manual page and I downloaded the manual from this.  There should be no need to run IP release / renew every 15 minutes on a decent working router. Have your ISP / Company help you with this issue. They may have supplied some firmware that prevents normal use.

Comment: If my ISP were that helpfull then I may have not posted this question here.

Comment: You may wish to escalate. You asked "How to set up PPPoE" and I answered that in full.  If the router needs ISP support to set it up, that was not evident in the question.